# Why is Groovy script trying to run as shell script?

Tags: groovy

The following script:

```
#!/opt/groovy-1.8.6/bin/groovy

final env = []
```

outputs:

```
$ ./small.groovy 
./small.groovy: line 3: final: command not found
```

What needs to be done to get it to run as Groovy (without having to call Groovy explicitly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are seeing that error, but the usual way to run Groovy scripts directly — in a Unix-like environment — is to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

println "Hello World"
```

This ensures that all environment variables are loaded correctly, such as `JAVA_HOME`.